# Blender 2.73 textures in solid view mode

Tags: texturing, game-engine, scene

When I was using blender 2.73, I realized that the option of "textured solid" is missing from the right pullout menu, when in previous versions it was put under "display".

[image]

I am aware that I could just change the view mode to textured. However, I am using the game engine, and I want one scene to have textures, while another I need to be in solid view mode. So is there any way in Blender 2.73 to have a "textured solid" mode without completely changing to textured mode?

Answer (score 1):

Texture Solid is in the 'Shading panel', which is below the 'Display' panel:

[image]

Comment: My shading menu doesn't have this. It only has a drop-down menu, and shadeless and backface culling options.

Comment: I have updated the image with one from Blender Internal instead of Cycles as I guess you are probably using that. If there is something else different it is because you are not using the latest version of blender (2.74).

Comment: I'm using the blender game engine. Sorry for not mentioning that!